# How to store a parametric matrix like a function in C++

Tags: c++, matrix, eigenvalue

I have a matrix M, whose each element is dependent on a single variable t in a different quadratic form without the constant.

Just for example,

```
M[1,1] = 2t^2 + 4t
M[3,2] = t^2 - 5t
M[2,4] = -t^2 + 5t
```

The matrix is acquired after a series of calculation and each element, or say, the coefficients before t^2 and t, are figured out through a combination of a bunch of other functions.

I was wondering how I can store the matrix like a function M(t) so each time I can call the function to generate a matrix with different t.

Thanks!

UPDATE:
The purpose is to get the smallest eigenvalue of the matrix given different t, so I was thinking I could generate a matrix each time and feed it to a eigenvalue solver to get the smallest eigenvalue for each t.

Comment: Write a function `double M(double t, int row, int col)`. Do *not* try to use square brackets to access the elements.

Comment: @n.m. Could you be more specific? You mean I return an array of array via this function?

Comment: Do you need to generate the matrix and store it, or can it be implied by the functions?

Comment: I believe the OP wants to return a matrix, something like Matrix m = parametricMatrix.createMatrix(5.345); IMHO, the parametric matrix and the explicit one should be model by two different objects (but it is difficult to judged without more context)

Comment: No, you don't return or have any arrays. You return an individual matrix cell.

Comment: No wait, I think I misunderstood the question. Please ignore my above comments.

Comment: Voted to close as unclear (I can think of solutions for at least three different interpretations of this question).

Comment: "The matrix is acquired after a series of calculation and each element is figured out through a combination of a bunch of other functions" Do you mean that each element is a quadratic function of one variable and its coefficients are calculated by some process?

Comment: You can write a function which stores the coefficients of the polys in two Matrix and calculates the returnig Matrix as: M(i,j) = t * (a(i,j) + t * b(i,j))

Comment: It is unclear what you are asking, but maybe expression templates are what you are after https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/More_C%2B%2B_Idioms/Expression-template

Comment: @n.m. Yes, the coefficients are calculated by other complex processes.

Comment: @Bob__ That's a good idea, actually. Btw, do you mean t^2 before a?

Comment: @James No, I mean t*(b + t * a) instead of a * t^2 + b * t. It's Horner's method (rule) to calculate polynomials.

Answer (score 1):

From my limited understanding, what you are after is a *function* at specific point, for this, I would use a `std::function<double(double)>` (i.e. function that takes one double and returns a double (the result.) I guess that's what you are after? And each location of the matrix can be initialized with a lambda - e.g

```
// Assume my dumb matrix is a 2d vector
vector<vector<function<double(double)>>> matrix;

matrix[1][1] = [](double t) { return /* formula for: 2t^2 + 4t */ ; }
```

etc.

Answer (score 0):

you should create a class name Matrix and this class has a constructor which has only one parameter t.

Answer (score 0):

```
// quadratic polynomial
class QuadPoly {
public:
    QuadPoly(double _c2, double _c1, double _c0) : c2(_c2), c1(_c1), c0(_c0) {}
    // ... other constructors, assignment
    double operator()(double t) const {return (c2*t+c1)*t+c0;}
    // ... maybe operator+ operator-, if necessary
private:
    double c0, c1, c2;
};

// numerical Matrix
template<class T> class Matrix {
public:
    // ... constructors, destructor, assignment
    const T& operator()(int row, int col) const;
    T& operator()(int row, int col);
    // ... anything else
    friend class QuadPolyMatrix;
private:
    int nRows, nCols;
    int nVals; // nRows*nCols
    double* pVals; // or maybe double**
};

// matrix of quadratic polynomials
class QuadPolyMatrix : public Matrix<QuadPoly> {
public:
    Matrix<double> operator() (double t) const;
};
```

Answer (score 0):

**1. Functions hardcoded**

If you really need a matrix object, you can make a class with t in constructor and function, which returns values.

```
class CMatrix {
public:
    CMatrix( double t_ ) : t( t_ ) {}

    double GetElement( int row, int col ) const {
        if( row == 3 && col == 2 ) {
            return t * t - t * 5;
        } else if( ) ...
    }

private:
    double t;
};
```

After that you can construct `CMatrix mat( t );`

And then get elements by `mat.GetElement( 3, 2 );`.

**2. More versatile variant.**

Make `typedef` of functions (they all have the same signature `double f( double t )`) and an array of pointers to functions. Then, you can make a `SetFunction` method, which sets a function in a given coordinate and `GetElement` calls function in given coordinate with parameter, which is stored in the field (like prev. example). But in this case you must set all needed functions before calling.